# How to update all records in the table that has no 0 at the beginning on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

In my table I have column that contains string with numbers. I need every string be next format:

```
5 numbers DOT 4 numbers
xxxxx.xxxx
```

Right now some of my numbers has `4 numbers DOT 4 numbers`, because numbers were imported from one excel file to another excel file and then in the database, and excel has cut 0 at the beginning of some numbers, so
I have:

```
08652.1501
08652.3000
08652.3000
1743.3017
7825.1001
1744.8200
04279.1010
```

But I need:

```
08652.1501
08652.3000
08652.3000
01743.3017
07825.1001
01744.8200
04279.1010
```

How to update my table? Check if string has format xxxx.xxxx then add 0 at the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE numberTable
SET number = '0' + number
WHERE LEN(number) = 9
```

is probably the simplest (assuming that the numbers are missing exactly on leading zero. A more general case could follow the same pattern for two missing zeroes, three missing zeroes, etc.

Comment: If that worked for you, would you mind accepting the answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Of course. It's just take some time before system allows to accept the answer

Comment: Forgot about the 15 minute time limit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field is `varchar` following should work..

```
UPDATE table SET field = (CONCAT('0', field )) WHERE field < 10000;
```